# ACO alias doesn't work with 'controllers/Controller' value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am new to ACLs in CakePHP. I believe my Administrator group is set up correctly with full access to the `'controllers'` ACO. However I get an error when I try to go to any controller or action that is not explicitly made public.

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check. Node references:
Aro: Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [email] => Admin
            [group_id] => 3
            [is_active] => 1
            [created] => 2013-04-08 07:59:52
            [modified] => 2013-04-08 07:59:52
            [Group] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Administrators
                    [user_count] => 2
                    [created] => 2013-04-08 06:34:58
                    [modified] => 2013-04-08 06:34:58
                )

        )

)

Aco: controllers/Users/index [CORE/Cake/Model/Permission.php, line 94]
```

In my `acos` table there is an entry for `'controllers/Users/index'` as the alias. This entry has a parent_id that references `'controllers/Users'`, which in turn has a parent_id which references `'controllers'`.

There is only one entry in my `'aros_acos'` table that is granting full permission to the Administrators group.

Based on the error above I did a little digging and found that if I directly try to call `$this->Acl->Aco->node('controllers/Users/index');` the returned value is `false`. But if I do the same query on `$this->Acl->Aco->node('controllers');` the returned value is the correct array.

Something is clearly not functioning properly but I can't figure out where I am going wrong. I have been digging in the Documentation Book and API all day and have not found any reason why `'controllers/Users/index'` isn't found but `'controllers'` is. At this point it seems like it has something to do with the `/` character but I don't know why. I used the same string when adding the Aco and it saved correctly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem by installing the ACL Plugin at:
http://www.alaxos.net/blaxos/pages/view/plugin_acl_2.0

After running this great utility I found that I was incorrectly adding my ACOs with the fill path in the alias. It turns out the alias is just the action or controller name and based on the parent_id's it finds the correct path.

This is not very well documented in the CakePHP Documentation, but what else is new.

Example:

I was adding `'controllers/Users/index'` instead of `'index'`.

Hope this can help someone else solve this problem! I wasted an entire day on it.